# Why can't I give multiple names to Spring's jdbc:embedded-database tag?

Tags: spring, jdbc

In my project I use an HSQLDB instance to serve for unit tests, and I do this by conveniently declaring a `<jdbc:embedded-database>` tag as Spring's doc said [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support).

Now for some reason I'd like to give it multiple names: `name="a,b,c"`, just like we usually do on normal Spring beans. However, I found the tag doesn't allow "name" attribute.

Maybe I can workaround this using aliases, but it seems ridiculous to me.

EDIT:
I want to know why Spring doesn't provide "name" for many special tags such as `<jdbc:embedded-database>`, `<util:list>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not a workaround and not ridiculous at all. In fact Spring parses the name of a bean definition separating it using comma as separator and create an alias internally for each "name".

If you open the source code of [`org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(Element, ParserContext)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java#58), you will see this on line 69:

```
String[] aliases = new String[0];
String name = element.getAttribute(NAME_ATTRIBUTE);
if (StringUtils.hasLength(name)) {
    aliases = StringUtils.trimArrayElements(StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(name));
}
BeanDefinitionHolder holder = new BeanDefinitionHolder(definition, id, aliases);
```

that is what you suggested from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out aliases are quite a standard way. But I still don't get why Spring doesn't provide "name" for many special tags such as `<jdbc:embedded-database>`, `<util:list>` etc. I think "name" attributes are more widely used. Besides, as a framework, having different configuration conventions makes Spring looks inconsistent.